# How to check a checkbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have set of images and checkboxes like below

```
<form name="food_type_form method="post" action="proc.php">
<img src="images/type_indian.jpg" alt="Select Indian food" />
<input type="checkbox" name="food_type[]" value="indian" />Indian

<img src="images/type_chinese.jpg" alt="Select Chinese food" />
<input type="checkbox" name="food_type[]" value="chinese" />Chinese

<img src="images/type_japanese.jpg" alt="Select Japanese food" />
<input type="checkbox" name="food_type[]" value="japanese" />Japanese / Sushi

<a href="#"  onclick="document.food_type_form.submit()">Show Restaurants >></a>
</form>
```

When the image is clicked i want to CHECK the checkbox below that image. If the checkboxes have different name we can do it with `document.myform.box1.checked = true;`

But how to check if it is a set of checkbox

**Edit 1**
NOTE : `<LABEL>` will not work, as i want to submit the form on image click.

Comment: Just 10 seconds late, & whew 3 answers are already posted.

Comment: What do you want? You want to check a checkbox AND submit the form when an image is clicked? Why do you want that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the image in a [label](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9) element.

Comment: +1 Not what was asked for, but best approach IMO, since it does not depend on JavaScript being enabled.

Comment: Wrapping the image alone won't do anything, a label needs to wrap the element in question or have a `for` pointing to it.

Comment: I want to submit the form once the image is clicked. So this will not work

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `<label>`, the default behavior is to invoke the action of it's child, so you can simple wrap each one, like this:

```
<label>
    <img src="images/type_indian.jpg" alt="Select Indian food" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="food_type[]" value="indian" />Indian
</label>
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/kzmD8/), this allows clicking the image, the checkbox or the text for selection, making it even more usable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the "[label](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)" element, for this example & your code should be like:-

```
<form name="food_type_form method="post" action="proc.php">

<label for="indian">
<img src="images/type_indian.jpg" alt="Select Indian food" />
<input type="checkbox" name="food_type[]" id="indian" value="indian" />Indian
</label>

<label for="chinese">
<img src="images/type_chinese.jpg" alt="Select Chinese food" />
<input type="checkbox" name="food_type[]" id="chinese" value="chinese" />Chinese
</label>

<label for="japanese">
<img src="images/type_japanese.jpg" alt="Select Japanese food" />
<input type="checkbox" name="food_type[]" id="japanese" value="japanese" />Japanese / Sushi
</label>

<a href="#"  onclick="document.food_type_form.submit()">Show Restaurants >></a>
</form>
```

Hope it helps.